# The file uploaded by the POST request is displayed as corrupted

Tags: reactjs, file-upload, axios, google-api

```
                    const boundary = "foo_bar_baz";
                    const delimiter = "\r\n--" + boundary + "\r\n";
                    const close_delim = "\r\n--" + boundary + "--";

                    let metadata = {
                        name: fileList[0].name,
                        mimeType: fileList[0].type,
                        parents: [response.data.id]
                    }

                    let body = 
                        delimiter +
                        'Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8\r\n\r\n' + 
                        JSON.stringify(metadata) + 
                        delimiter +
                        'Content-Type: ' + fileList[0].type + '\r\n' +
                        'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n' +
                        '\r\n' +multipartReauestBody  + close_delim;

                    console.log(body);

                    axios({
                        method: "post",
                        url: "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?supportsTeamDrives=true&uploadType=multipart",
                        headers: {
                            Authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken,
                            "Content-Type": "multipart/related; boundary=foo_bar_baz"
                        },
                        data: body
                }).then(response => console.log(response)).catch(error => console.log(error))
```

The code above is to upload files to the shared drive using GOOGLE API.

```
const getBase64 = (file) => {
    let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    reader.onload = () => {
        console.log(multipartReauestBody= btoa(reader.result));
        console.log(multipartReauestBody);
    }
};


const uploadHandler = (files) => {
    const filesLength = files.length;
    for(let i = 0; i < filesLength; i++) {
        const file = files[i];
        fileList.push(file);
        getBase64(file);
    }
}
```

The upload handler works when selecting a file through the tag.
getBase64 converts the selected file into base64.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Everything seemed to work well as shown in the picture below. (A file has been created on the shared drive.)

[image]

However, when I click the generated file, I see an error that I cannot open the file.
[image]

And when I open the file in the notepad, it looks like the base64 code converted using getBase64.
[image]

Below is what appears when the original file is opened as a notepad.
[image]

As a result of checking the file size, the uploaded file was about 15,000 bytes larger than the original file.

How can I modify the code so that I can see the same content as the original file? Please help me.

Comment: what is the mime type?

Comment: mimetype is application/pdf